# PdfParser in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdfparser

I'm trying to use the PdfParser library ( [PDFparser link](https://pdfparser.org/) ) in Codeigniter, so first of all I have downloaded, unzipped and installed the library under third_party/vendor folder, additional I have downloaded, unzipped and installed the 
tcpdf library in the same third_party/vendor folder.
Since I cannot run Composer on my remote server I have created a autoload.php file into the thir_party/vendor folder.
The folder structure is now the following one:

```
third_party
   vendor
      autoload.php
      tecnickcom
         tcpdf
      smalot
         pdfparser
            src
               Smalot
                  PdfParser
```

The code into the autoload file to load all the dependencies is the following:

```
    $vendorDir = '../vendor';
$tcpdf_files = Array(
    'Datamatrix' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/barcodes/datamatrix.php',
    'PDF417' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/barcodes/pdf417.php',
    'QRcode' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/barcodes/qrcode.php',
    'TCPDF' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
    'TCPDF2DBarcode' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php',
    'TCPDFBarcode' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf_barcodes_1d.php',
    'TCPDF_COLORS' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_colors.php',
    'TCPDF_FILTERS' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_filters.php',
    'TCPDF_FONTS' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_fonts.php',
    'TCPDF_FONT_DATA' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_font_data.php',
    'TCPDF_IMAGES' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_images.php',
    'TCPDF_IMPORT' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf_import.php',
    'TCPDF_PARSER' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf_parser.php',
    'TCPDF_STATIC' => $vendorDir . '/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php'
);

foreach ($tcpdf_files as $key => $file) {
    include_once $file;
}

include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Document.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Header.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Object.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Encoding.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Font.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Page.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Pages.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementArray.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementBoolean.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementString.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementDate.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementHexa.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementMissing.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementName.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementNull.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementNumeric.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementStruct.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Element/ElementXRef.php";

include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Encoding/StandardEncoding.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Encoding/ISOLatin1Encoding.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Encoding/ISOLatin9Encoding.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Encoding/MacRomanEncoding.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Font/FontCIDFontType0.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Font/FontCIDFontType2.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Font/FontTrueType.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Font/FontType0.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Font/FontType1.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/XObject/Form.php";
include_once  $vendorDir . "/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/XObject/Image.php";
```

I have created a new file into Codeigniter library folder, the file is named Pdfparser.php and its content is the following:

```
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pdfparser {
    function __construct() {
        require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
    }
}
```

In the controller, I load the libray file manually with:

```
$this->load->library('pdfparser');
```

The problem is that when I try to instantiate the class with

```
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Smalot\PdfParser\Parser' not found
```

Any suggestion to fix this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Aside - You don't need to run composer on the remote, just a way to upload the stuff that composer did locally. like `scp` or `sftp`, or even just commit it into version control (not recommended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you use version control?

Install the libs via composer locally (I see you just downloaded and unzipped - that won't work). Just use the normal directory structure of `vendor`.

You should have a `composer.json` and `composer.lock` in your project root. After installing, composer also creates classmap files etc, which it needs in order to find your classes.

So. You can either put the vendor folder into Git (which can get a little messy depending how often you run composer commands), or you can just use a tool like `scp` to securely copy and deploy the vendor files into place.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. Silly me...I thought I needed Composer on my remote server to. So, on my local PC I have created the composer.json file into an empty folder...running the composer update command I got all the vendor folder with pdfparser and needed dependencies. I have uploaded the vendor folder into the third_party folder in remote server and I get no error when loading the library I wrote above. Still getting 500 server error when trying to parse the PDF file, but no log is created in the remote server...weird...

Comment: I have isolated the error...is in the following line $pdf = $parser->parseFile($path_to_file);

Comment: Fixed...the server error was due to Exception not correctly catched by my script